# Scroll is not coming up and contents getting hidden in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have page structure like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        some fixed contents
    </div>
</div>

<div class='row' style="overflow-y: scroll, position: absolute;">
    <div class='col-xs-1'></div>
    <div class='col-xs-10'>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-1'></div>
</div>


<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        some fixed contents
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to draw  a scroll bar if they don't fit into screen. Extra contents inside ui-view getting hidden.

What changes are needed for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to  set height in CSS to see vertical scroll bar.

```
#inner-sroll {
height: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[W3schools-overflow-link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)